# Sorting by date in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I want to sort a table by date in ascending order. The table also contains null values.

I want to display data in Gridview. I want to display the data like first all rows which contains date field and then date as blank field.

I used below query :

```
select * from TempTable order by convert(datetime, Date,101) asc
```

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Then you should check for `null` values:

```
Select * FROM TempTable 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN datetime IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC 
,  Date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from TempTable 
order by case when [Date] is null then 1 else 0 end, [Date]
```